# POST, DELETE not sending response via stream_context_create() / fopen()

Tags: php, http, http-post, fopen, http-delete

I have the following code that I use to post data via HTTP

```
        $opts = array (
                'http' => array (
                    'method' => "POST",
                    'header' => $auth ,
                    //  . "Content-Type: " . $content_type . "\r\n"
                    //  . "Content-length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n",
                    'user_agent' => RESTClient :: USER_AGENT,
                    'content' => $data                      
                )
        );
        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        $fp = fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);
        $result = "";
        while ($str = fread($fp,1024)) {
            $result .= $str;
        }
        fclose($fp);


     Return $result;
```

It is posting as when I look in the database the the posted data has been entered, however, my code shouldbe bringing back a response.  The responses work correctly when I use cURL but not via this method.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Except for a warning/notice because of the missing Content-type this

```
<?php
class RESTClient {
    const USER_AGENT='Mozilla';
}
$url = 'http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/';
$data = 'query=test&ac=3';
$auth = '';

// <-- unaltered code
$opts = array (
    'http' => array (
        'method' => "POST",
        'header' => $auth ,
        //  . "Content-Type: " . $content_type . "\r\n"
        //  . "Content-length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n",
        'user_agent' => RESTClient :: USER_AGENT,
        'content' => $data
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$fp = fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);
$result = "";
while ($str = fread($fp,1024)) {
    $result .= $str;
}
fclose($fp);
//  unaltered code -->
echo $result;
```

works fine for me.
Does this code snippet produce the described behaviour on system?

---

btw: instead of fopen/while/fread/fclose you can also use [file_get_contents](http://docs.php.net/file_get_contents).

Comment: If I use the DELETE method.  There is no data or content type to send but I should still get a response, to say whether the delte has been successful or not, but I don't.